# Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts even when using Test.setMock

Tags: apex, trigger, httpcalloutmock

I'm working on a SOAP integration and everything is working fine but I'm facing this error in the test class even when I'm using Test.setMock. I read in some forum that the callout could be executing in the MakeData, since it is inside the trigger of my object. But in theory it should not since certain conditions must be met for such a call to be made. Any idea why it continues marking this error?

Trigger

```
Trigger OrderTrigger on Order__c (after update) {    
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Order__c ord : Trigger.new) {
            String oldStatus = Trigger.oldMap.get(ord.Id).Status__c;
            if (oldStatus != 'Complete' && ord.Status__c == 'Complete') {
                CalloutService.callExternalService(ord.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web Service

```
public class CalloutService {

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callExternalService(Id orderID) {
        Order__c objOrder = [SELECT OrderRef__c, Total_Amount__c FROM Order__c WHERE Id = :orderID LIMIT 1];
        ServiceCredentials__c servCred = ServiceCredentials__c.getValues('ExternalServiceCredential');
        ServiceProxy.order newOrder = new ServiceProxy.order();
        newOrder.username = servCred.Username__c;
        newOrder.password = servCred.Password__c;
        newOrder.orderid = objProject.OrderRef__c;
        newOrder.totalAmount = objOrder.Total_Amount__c ;
        
        ServiceProxy.InvoicesPortSoap11 externalService = new ServiceProxy.InvoicesPortSoap11();
        String response = externalService.createOrder(newOrder);
        System.debug('Callout response: ' + response);
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class CalloutServiceTest {
    @testSetup
    private static void makeData () {
        ServiceCredentials__c servCred = new ServiceCredentials__c();
        servCred.Name = 'ExternalServiceCredential';
        servCred.Username__c = 'someUser';
        servCred.Password__c = 'somePassword';
        insert servCred;

        Order__c newOrder = new Order__c();
        newOrder.Name = 'My test Order';
        newOrder.Total_Amount__c = 30000;
        newOrder.OrderRef__c = '0018rll002XigXyAAJ';
        insert newOrder;
    }
    
    @isTest
    private static void testCallExternalServiceSuccess () {
        String orderName = 'My test Order';
        Id orderID = [SELECT Id FROM Order__c WHERE Name = :orderName LIMIT 1].Id;
        
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new ExternalCalloutServiceMock());
        Test.startTest();
        try {        
            CalloutService.callExternalService(orderID);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('CalloutException: '+ e);        
        }
        Test.stopTest();        
    }
}
```

Lastly, anyone knows how to get the Mock response since a future method is of type void?

Tanks!

Comment: I suspect you have some other automation (perhaps a record triggered flow or some other declarative automation, or even other Apex) that is being invoked due to setup or other processing in your unit test.

Comment: You can discover this easily enough by capturing debug logs for the test run.